# Is GCC ready for C++14 production code?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

In [this web page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html), GCC's support for the ISO C++14 standard is defined "**experimental**".

Since I'd like to use some of the C++14's improvements on C++11 (e.g. `std::make_unique` and generic lambdas) in my C++ code, am I safe in using the `-std=c++14` option with GCC 4.9 for production code, or is current GCC/C++14 status kind of like "beta" and so GCC/C++14 not ready for production code?

Comment: IMO, it can't be ready until C++11 support is finished (ie: codecvt, et al).

Comment: This might possibly be helpful - [GCC C++ 2014 Implementation Status](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2014)

Comment: @Brandon: I think GCC developers could target C++14 as a whole, instead of separating the C++11 parts from C++14, e.g. if there are useful features in C++14, these could be prioritized over less useful features of C++11. On the other hand, even if things like codecvt et al. are not finished, would you consider GCC ready for production quality C++11 code?

Comment: Yes. I would consider it for production code. I use it in production code and in a lot of cases (for me), it optimises better than clang and MSVC. It's many times better than 4.8.2 already.

Comment: @Brandon GCC 5.0 will have a full support for C++11 and C++14 libraries. On the other hand, I would probably wait for 5.0.1 or 5.0.2 for production.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I did simple tests and noted that GCC 4.9.1 seems to correctly accept C++14 features like generic lambdas (which can be convenient) with the `-std=c++14` option. So even if the library is not 100% C++14 compliant (or not even 100% C++11 compliant...), it might be convenient to use the `-std=c++14` compilation mode, to enjoy those C++14 features currently implemented.

Comment: @Brandon, why would missing features affect the features that are present? Why would `make_unique` be unsuitable for production use because Unicode conversion facets are not implemented? Does it depend on them for correctness? (Rhetorical question, having implemented all of them I know it doesn't ;-)

Comment: @Morwenn, GCC's release numbering scheme has changed. What you refer to as 5.0.1 will be 5.2 and 5.0.2 will be 5.3

Comment: @JonathanWakely: you made a really good point, thanks. I'm happy to mark as answer something like your comment. This is the same thing I was thinking: I'd like to use for example C++14 generic lambdas in my C++ code: if they are currently implemented in GCC I'm happy to compile with `-std=c++14` and enjoy them, even if Unicode conversion facets are not yet implemented.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Beats me. I follow the libstdc++ mailing list but I totally missed the numbering scheme change. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is current GCC/C++14 status kind of like "beta" and so GCC/C++14 not ready for production code?

It depends which features you use. `make_unique` is very simple, was easy to implement, and should be safe to rely on.

Some of the other new features (especially core language features) took a lot more work to implement and might have more bugs waiting to be found and fixed.

So there's no single "it's ready" or "it's not ready" answer.

However, one important thing to be aware of is that while it's still labelled as experimental there is no attempt to maintain backward compatibility between GCC 4.x and GCC 5, for instance. So if you have C++11 code built with GCC 4.8 you need to recompile it all if you want to link to other C++11/C++14 objects built with 4.9, and similarly if/when you move to GCC 5: recompile all objects that use C++11 or C++14 (because types such as `std::tuple` changed data layout in GCC 5).

For C++03 code we don't change definitions between releases, so they are stable.

Comment: I think the same applies also to other compilers like MSVC :) BTW, changing data layout is not a problem: it's very common for MSVC (they changed data layout for several STL classes between different versions of Visual Studio).

Comment: @Mr.C64, it's not a problem _for MSVC_. But I promise you it's a huge problem for a lot of GCC users, which is why GCC has not changed its C++ ABI since GCC 3.4

Comment: Amazing! If I correctly understood what you wrote, it's kind of like MSVC hadn't changed C++ ABI (e.g. STL class layouts) _since VS2005!_ :)